# extracting mp3 file duration using AudioQueueServices

Tags: iphone, mp3, core-audio, audioqueueservices

I have implemented a streaming mp3 player using AudioQueueServices, that downloads mp3s over an NSURLConnection.   Playback, pausing, and seeking work great, however I can't figure out how to extract the duration of the audio from the mp3 files while they are still being downloaded.  I'd like to be able to pull the info from the id3 tags but am clueless as to how to do that.  Any thoughts?

Comment: it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246637/iphone-get-duration-of-an-audio-file

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly view the duration of the Mp3 file, but you can work it out by file size, a song that is 3 minuets long is between 1 megabyte.