# iPhone: get duration of an audio file

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What is the easiest way to get a duration of an audio file?

I could create an object of AVAudioPlayer, initialize it with URL and than get the duration, but this way is too long. Is there an easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the duration of an audio file in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219379/how-to-get-the-duration-of-an-audio-file-in-ios)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the Audio File Services functions. There's one property to get that should give you the estimated duration. Code:

```
    NSURL *afUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    AudioFileID fileID;
    OSStatus result = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)afUrl, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &fileID);
    Float64 outDataSize = 0;
    UInt32 thePropSize = sizeof(Float64);
    result = AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyEstimatedDuration, &thePropSize, &outDataSize);
    AudioFileClose(fileID);
```

You can check the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/musicaudio/reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand, why do I get every time that outDataSize equals to 0?

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I found out where the problem was.

Comment: Hey, that's not fair at all, using actual knowledge to get the check, instead of vague speculation about an OS you've never even worked with.  :)

Comment: @Ilya: Glad it worked!
@MusiGenesis: I have to use actual knowledge on some answer!

Comment: gotcha...the datatype must be Float64 not UIInt64!

Answer (score 15):

Correct code is

```
NSURL *afUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AudioFileID fileID;
OSStatus result = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)afUrl, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &fileID);
Float64 outDataSize = 0;
UInt32 thePropSize = sizeof(Float64);
result = AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyEstimatedDuration, &thePropSize, &outDataSize);
AudioFileClose(fileID);
```

outDataSize should be Float64 not UInt64.

Comment: I've been coding objective-c for a day now so excuse the novice question. How do I get the outDataSize into an int that holds milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you know anything about the audio file in question (samplerate, bitdepth, channel count), and it's an uncompressed format (WAV/AIFF), then you can calculate the /approximate/ duration from the filesize:

length_in_seconds = (file_length-guess_100_bytes_for_header) / (samplerate*(bitdepth*channel_count/8))

Comment: 100 bytes for the header? Whatever happened to the canonical 44?  :)

Comment: I should know better after 14 years of this, but just last month I spent half a day trying to figure out where the little click at the beginning of my sound was coming from. I was using my quick-and-dirty method that assumed just the 44 byte header. I learned my lesson, yet again.

Comment: You can take dataOffset which I guess indicates the header size.

`SInt64 dataOffset = 0;
UInt32 dataOffsetSize = sizeof(dataOffset);  

AudioFileStreamGetProperty(inAudioFileStream, kAudioFileStreamProperty_DataOffset, &dataOffsetSize, &dataOffset);`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the file type.  If it's a WAV file you can locate the file's header and determine the playback duration that way.  If it's a compressed format (*.mp3 etc.) you're better off sticking to the method you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Combining AVAudioPlayer with Swift becomes as easy as (I am migrating a Realm table below, but you get the idea):

```
import AVFoundation

let resource = old!["filename"] as? String
let afUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(resource, withExtension: nil)
let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: afUrl!)

new!["duration"] = Double(player.duration)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone lands here looking for a way to get the duration for both audio and video files, have a look at this answer to another post, which instead uses `AVAsset` instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7052147/381233

Using `AudioFileGetProperty` (like the other two main answers here) to get the duration of A/V files didn't work for a few *.mov* files on my device (result was always 0), while the solution using `AVAsset` got the duration for all audio and video files on my device.

(Interestingly enough, however, the duration from both solutions was sometimes 1 second more than that displayed in the UI of an actual `AVAudioPlayer`. Most likely the `AVAudioPlayer` uses a non-standard rounding routine for the displayed duration.)

Answer (score 1):

sample code from answer [How to get the duration of an audio file in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219379/how-to-get-the-duration-of-an-audio-file-in-ios). This is the best answer.

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audioFileURL options:nil]; 
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration; 
float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:mp3_url options:nil];
                    [audioAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"duration"] completionHandler:^{
                        CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
                        float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);

                        NSLog(@"duration:%f",audioDurationSeconds);
                    }];
```