# How to get the uncompressed file size of an MP3 file using CoreAudio API

Tags: iphone, streaming, mp3, core-audio

Using CoreAudio, I am able to get the sampleRate (frames per second) and the file size, but in order to get the "total" time of the song, I need to know the Real file size of that compressed mp3.

```
        AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;
        UInt32 asbdSize = sizeof(asbd);

        // get the stream format.
        err = AudioFileStreamGetProperty(inAudioFileStream, kAudioFileStreamProperty_DataFormat, &asbdSize, &asbd);
        if (err)
        {
            [self failWithErrorCode:AS_FILE_STREAM_GET_PROPERTY_FAILED];
            return;
        }

        sampleRate = asbd.mSampleRate;
```

Is there any way I can know the real size of the song using Objective-C?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246637/iphone-get-duration-of-an-audio-file/1246727#1246727)

There's a property you can ask in `AudioFileGetProperty` called `kAudioFilePropertyEstimatedDuration` that should do the trick.

Comment: hi pgb, I looked at your answer on the other post u linked to, but I always got the outDataSize  to be 0 every time. Can you help me with this? thanks